# Magento - Free theme. How do I delete the link at the bottom of each page which advertises the company

Tags: magento

The company offering the free theme have placed a link on the bottom of each page which directly sends you to their website.  I cannot find where the link is to remove it. Can anyone tell me how to find and remove it?

Comment: I agree with @Zyava, you may be violating the terms of using the theme if you remove that.  Be sure to read the license agreement to avoid getting in any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch in

```
System->Confugration->Design
```

there might be something about footer contents.

Moreover if you can grep, the grep link url or link text.

Moreover check .js files and check php. For example, once threre might be such thing as base64_decode